# Error 405 when trying to make request from fluttter using flask

Tags: python, flutter, dart, flask

I am trying to make a post request from flutter using flask but it's giving a 405 error, But when I try to make a post request from Postman it gives the output.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, flash, jsonify
import pickle
import numpy as np
model=pickle.load(open('model1.pkl','rb'))
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/predict',methods=['POST'])    
def predictor():
    area=int(request.args['area'])
    bedrooms=int(request.args['bedrooms'])
    psf=float(request.args['psf'])
    feature_score=int(request.args['feature_score'])
    LocationPremium=float(request.args['LocationPremium'])
    LogPremium=float(request.args['LogPremium'])
    query=np.array([[area,bedrooms,psf,feature_score,LocationPremium,LogPremium]])
    result= model.predict(query)[0]
    return jsonify({'prediction':str(result)}) 
  
                     
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
    app.run(host='10.0.2.2', port=8000)
```

Comment: Would you please [edit] your question and add the Flutter code snippet that does the request? The Python side looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to set the `Accept` header to `application/json`